# Zero power after new Gfci installed

Tags: electrical

While using hairdryer power went out. Nothing was tripped in the breaker panel. The gfci switch would not reset. Bought new gfci switch and replaced it for old one. Still no power in master bathroom, hall bath outlet does not work either as well as a few other outlets in different rooms. Is this possibly a burnt wire? Electrician came in and tested breaker box and all light switches and outlets in the home. All was fine except the original issue which still read at 0. He was unable to diagnose the problem. He suggest running new wire from gfci outlet to the panel..... is this safe if it is a faulty or burnt wire? Since the wire was not found.. just worried is all I don’t need a bigger problem on top of what I already have. Any advice???

Answer (score 2):

I would expect this to be a wiring problem, but there is a 99% chance the problem is at one of the ends of wires, i.e. Where they connect to a device like an outlet, switch or splice.

Code requires that all junction points be accessible in junction boxes.  Almost all junction boxes are behind switches, outlets, lamps, or other points of use.

So I would shut off the breaker and note what things have lost power.  It is likely a wire connection problem at one of them.

It almost has to be at the last one which is working or the first one that failed, but that depends on the idea of them being in a "string" one to the next to the next, and it is often difficult to guess where those are.

The #1 type of wire connection problem is called a "backstab".  We have a lot of Q&A about those.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing seems to be wired in a line. Every outlet has been replaced. Every light switch has been checked. The breaker box isn’t labeled clearly and is incorrect. The master bath outlet is where the problem started and jumps to the master closet light down to the closet outlet. The jumps to the neighboring kitchen where only 1 outlet affected on the wall is not working which is for the gas stove. The kitchen light above the stove and island were affected as well.

Comment: Then skips over joined dining room as well as next room which is laundry room and power out in hall bathroom outlet but the light and exhaust work. the outlet on outside of home is not working (which we’ve also replaced) if it helps it’s a double mobile home. 1991. All started 4 am nobody awake but me and power went out after 3 min using blow dryer. The lights dimmed slightly while using the dryer then power went out. Short of taking down walls/ or chilling how can I find the wire that is bad/faulty? Believe the wire leads up into ceiling from the master bathroom outlet which is a gfci outlet